# Interface on emulator not the same in xml file

Tags: android-studio

[do i have to uninstall the software ? Is there any other ways to solve the problem? I tried to create new project, but the same problem happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Zaz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall anything.  
You are using a `ConstraintLayout` but you have not set any constraints to your views, so they all show in the upper portion of the screen and they overlap.  
Set the necessary constraints so that they are fixed where you want them.  
More info at 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout